# How do you choose where to put information based on an index into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

In MATLAB, the loop I create looks like:

```
header_names = {'InvoiceNo','Customer',...}

for i = 1:length(x)
    entry(index+i,:) = [InvoiceNo, Customer,...]
end
% Create a table from the data.
fin_table = cell2table(entry,'VariableNames',header_names);

% Write to the finish file.
writetable(fin_table,finish);
```

With the table values and headers, I will end up getting something that looks like:

| InvoiceNo | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | Jimmy |
| 1001 | Bob |
| 1002 | Max |
| 1003 | April |
| 1004 | Tom |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |

I would like to know how to accomplish this in Python. My main question is how do I create the entry? How do I put a table in a for loop and ask it to print information on the next row for each iteration?

In Python, I currently have the following:

```
        for i in range(len(item)):
            entry = pd.DataFrame(
                [InvoiceNo, Customer, invoice, due, terms, Location, memo, item[i], item[i], quan[i], rate[i], taxable,
                 tax_rate, invoice, email, Class],
                columns=['InvoiceNo', 'Customer', 'InvoiceDate', 'DueDate', 'Terms', 'Location', 'Memo', 'Item',
                         'ItemDescription', 'ItemQuantity', 'ItemRate', 'ItemAmount', 'Taxable', 'TaxRate',
                         'ServiceDate', 'Email', 'Class'])
        # Increment the index for entry values to be correct.
        index += len(item)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Is your data saved in a csv file?

Comment: @Ted input data is saved in xlsx file. That is where I get original info from. Once I create the new table with the updated information, I will be sending the new data based on 'entry' to a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not get your question completely, I will try to give you some tools that might be useful:

To get input value you can use (and put this inside of a 'for' loop depending on the number of rows you want to create)

```
new_InvoiceNo= input("Enter InvoiceNo:\n")
new_Customer= input("Enter Customer:\n")
new_invoice = input("Enter invoice:\n")
...
```

then you can either append these values as list into the main DF :

```
to_append = [new_InvoiceNo, new_Customer, new_invoice, ...]
new_values = pd.Series(to_append, index = df.columns)
df = df.append(new_values , ignore_index=True)
```

or , you can use '.loc' method:

```
to_append = [new_InvoiceNo, new_Customer, new_invoice, ...]
df_length = len(df)
df.loc[df_length] = to_append
```

Try to implement this in your code and report it back here.

Comment: Awesome, I will look into this tomorrow and see what I find. I will let you know then what I get. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so that worked!! Here is what I did:
`for i in range(len(item)): entry_new = pd.Series([InvoiceNo, Customer, invoice, due, terms, Location, memo, item[i], item[i], quan[i], rate[i], taxable, tax_rate, invoice, email, Class])
entry = entry.append(entry_new, ignore_index=True)
# Increment the index for entry values to be correct.
index += len(item)`
This created an array with all the values I want in "entry". After this I will put the headers in the dataframe. But this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Very good, which one of the two methods are using ?